# What are the rules here?

Tags: number-sequence

If you follow our rules, and you start with **1 and 5** then it goes into

> **1**, **5**, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1,...

If you follow our rules, and you start with **14 and 2** then it goes into

> **14**, **2**, 10, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2,...

If you follow our rules, and you start with **2 and 14** then it goes into

> **2**, **14**, 2, 10, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2,...

If you follow our rules, and you start with **9 and 3** then it goes into

> **9**, **3**, 3, 3, 3,...

If you follow our rules, and you start with **26 and 61** then it goes into

> **26**, **61**, 26, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,...

Comment: What's the source of this puzzle?

Comment: @NathanHinchey No source, just created it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor refinement on [athin's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/67074/49531) to account for the last sequence:

> Denote the last two numbers in the sequence are $A$ and $B$ (initially there are only two numbers).
>
>  If $A < B$, append $A$ to the sequence;
>  else, append the greater of $A-2B$ and 0.

Comment: But, for $1 1$, it should be $1$ not $0$ on the first sequence.

Comment: Good point! My answer does not account for all of them!

Answer (score 9):

It's possible that the rule is:

> Denote the last two numbers in the sequence are $A$ and $B$ (initially there are only two numbers).
>
>  If $A < B$, append $A$ to the sequence;
>   else, append $|A-2B|$.

Comment: In this case, the last sequence is wrong!

Comment: you need a second "if":  if $A>2B$, append $|A-2B|$, else append $A - 2$ (or $B - 1$?).

Comment: Oh, and if $A=B$, append $A$ (or $B$).

Comment: Whoops I just realized this.. and uh tbh it's rather hacky to have 3 ifs btw :(